# Error: The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, build.gradle

My gradle version is `2.2` in Project's gradle wrapper properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2- 
all.zip
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

I am getting an error while building the `apk`

> The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
>   Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)

Answer (score 3):

As you can clearly see you are using very old version of gradle in your project which is no more supported.

Make sure that latest gradle version `gradle-4.4` is installed on your machine. Also make sure you are using latest `Android Stdio 3.1.4`.

Once you have above latest setup, then make below changes in your project files:

project `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

project `gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```